# Reading in first line of csv file and saving to a list without using ',' split

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

I have a csv file that I need to read in the first line and save it to a List.  Only problem is there are commas in some of the text and it is splitting in the middle of a field when I need it not to.  Unfortunately I cannot change the data inside so whats there needs to stay.  I currently also write the data to csv so I was thinking maybe instead of using a comma I can use a different character.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  I have been researching but am not coming up with a proper answer.  Here is my code below:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace TestJSON
{
    class Program
    {

    static void Main()
    {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText(
                          @"C:\Users\nphillips\workspace\2016R23\UITestAutomation\SeedDataGenerator\src\staticresources\seeddata.resource"));
            string fileName = "";            
            var bundles = data.RecordSetBundles;

            foreach (var bundle in bundles)
            {
                var records = bundle.Records;
                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    var test = record.attributes;
                    foreach (var testagain in test)
                    {
                        // Getting the object Name Ex. Location, Item, etc.
                        var jprop = testagain as JProperty;
                        if (jprop != null)
                        {
                             fileName = jprop.First.ToString().Split('_')[2]+ ".csv";
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    string header = "";
                    string value = "";
                    foreach (var child in record)
                    {                     
                        var theChild = child as JProperty;
                        if (theChild != null && !theChild.Name.Equals("attributes"))
                        {
                            header += child.Name + ",";
                            value += child.Value.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    value += "+" + Environment.NewLine;

                    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                    {
                        header += "+" + Environment.NewLine;
                        File.WriteAllText(fileName, header);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // Need to read in here
                        var readCSV = new StreamReader(fileName);
                        var splits = readCSV.ReadLine();

                    }
                    File.AppendAllText(fileName, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of free .NET CSV parsers out there that properly handle commas within quoted fields.  You should use one.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) is a good one I've used.

Comment: You have two solutions 1) change your delimiter character to something that won't appear in the text or 2) encode your commas as &comma; (say) before saving and decode on reading.

Comment: @ChrisF, 3) use an actual CSV parser.  That is, provided the "CSV file" is truly a CSV file and fields with commas are properly quoted.  If the "CSV file" doesn't follow the rules of the CSV format, then your suggestions might be necessary.

Comment: @adv12 - true, but if the csv file doesn't have quoted fields then the OP is stuck.

Comment: @Darren, CSV files are text files that follow a specific set of rules, like XML files or JSON files or any other text-based structured data file.

Comment: @NicolePhillips, on first read I missed that *you* are the one generating these CSV files.  If that's the case, you need to generate them according to the rules of the [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).  If the fields you are writing contain commas, they need to be surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how the file is delimited. I would guess that this file is tab delimited, so split on that instead.

Assuming your line is called myCSVLine... I.E

```
string seperator = "\t";
string[] splitLine = myCSVLine.Split(seperator.ToCharArray());
```

`splitLine` would now have all of your strings, including ones with commas